# Configuration IIS as a proxy service

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-10

I'm configuring IIS as a reverse proxy server on Windows 10. I have asp net core web service that launched on http://localhost:5050. I want to route http request from `https://localhost/api/myservice` to `http://localhost:5050`. How should I configure my IIS to do this?

I did following:

- Add a new "Proxy server" in URL-rewrite section
- Set "Pattern" as "(.*)/api/myservice
- Set "Action Type" as "Rewrite" and "Rewrite URL" as "http://localhost:5050"
- Checked "Append query string"

Frankly speaking, I tried so many ways to configure IIS but there is still no success. Also could someone explain what do strings "{R:1}" or "{C:2}" mean?

Comment: You have your new IIS server bound to port 443? What does your failure look like?

Comment: Yup, it bounds to 443.
Service get no httprequest if I type ```https://localhost/api/myservice``` in browser

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Blank Rule to your site bound to 443 and configure according to the image.

The `{R:1}` refers to the first match from the rule's regular expression. So a regex like `He(.*)o, wo(.*)d!` has two match groups. If matched against the string `Hello, world!`, the complete matching string can be referenced in the rewrite URL as `{R:0}`, the `ll` as `{R:1}`, and the `rl` as `{R:2}`.

In your pattern `(.*)/api/template`, anything matched before /api/template would be `{R:1}` - so the string `/some/path/api/template` would have `/some/path` as `{R:1}`. In the pattern I configure below in the image, `^/api/template(?:/(.*))?`, subpaths under /api/template are captured as `{R:1}`. So the string `/api/template/index.html` would have `{R:1}` as `index.html`.

The `{C:x}` references refer to Condition variables that you wouldn't use in a basic rewrite scenario like this.

[image: IIS Blank Rule]

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) for a great example of your scenario.